# One liner to get a reference on a property, and initialize it if it doesn't exist

Tags: php

I'm used to JavaScript where I often write things like this: `const ref = obj.arr || (obj.arr = []);`.

With one line of code, this gives me a **reference** on `obj.arr` after having initialized it to empty array if it didn't exist.

I'm trying to do the same in PHP but I'm struggling with ampersands, since the assignation is done by copy of value by default. Here is my failing attempt which I thought it would work:

```
$ref= &$obj['arr'] ?? &($obj['arr'] = []);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, a ternary operator should suffice:

```
$obj['arr'] = isset($obj['arr']) ? $obj['arr'] : [];
$ref = &$obj['arr']);
```

Comment: I think this copies the value, and it doesn't assign `$obj['arr']` either

Comment: @GuerricP aggreed !

Comment: @GuerricP see my edit. They might just have to use two lines. PHP isn't as flexible as Javascript.

Comment: I suppose you're right, upvoting to balance the other guy's downvote